# Android mokito When(), thenReturn() is not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mockito, android-testing

I am writing test code using Android Mockito framework. I wrote the code to mock SharedPreference in the class to be tested. For this, SharedPreference was stubed using When() thenReturn(). As a result of debugging, null is continuously returned and the app dies with NullPointerException. Here is my code :

**Test Code** :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExampleUnitTest {

    @Mock
    public Context context;

    @Mock
    public SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    @Mock
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    TestA mTestA;
    String tempStringData = "";

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        when(context.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(sharedPref);
        when(sharedPref.edit()).thenReturn(editor);
        when(sharedPref.getString(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(tempStringData);

        mTestA = new TestA(context);
    }
}
```

**TestA.class** :

```
public class TestA {
    
    SharedPreference mSharedPref;

    public TestA(Context context) {
        mSharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.shrf_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // return 'null'
    }
}
```

I think I did the stub correctly, but why does it keep returning null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`anyString()` does not allow `null` objects.

`context.getString(R.string.shrf_file_key)` returns null.

If you want to allow null values as well, you can use `nullable(String.class)`

Comment: Thank you very much! The cause was me. ;D

Answer (score 1):

Your test class method looks a little bit weird.

You are using following method calls within `TestA`  constructor

```
mSharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.shrf_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Therefore you should mock following method calls

```
 context.getSharedPreferences(...)
 context.getString(...)
```

like this

```
 when(context.getString(eq(R.string.shrf_file_key)).thenReturn(tempStringData);  
 when(context.getSharedPreferences(eq(tempStringData), eqInt(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)).thenReturn(sharedPref);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have checked a little more closely, but that's my fault ;D